# How do I make a count Timer in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working on a game, and i want the program to stops the game after 1 second, how do I do that?

Comment: what have you tried/what do you even want to achieve/what is a 'count timer supposed to be ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

> ```
>  [self performSelector:@selector(stop) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with an [`NSTimer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/index.html):

```
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
                                              target:self
                                            selector:@selector(stopGame)
                                            userInfo:nil
                                             repeats:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this if you want the timer to get fired every 1 second or whatever delay you want on it..

Doing it, declaring a property..

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer *myTimer;

self.myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(myTask) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

or without one..

```
NSTimer *myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(myTask) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

The `myTask` function is set to get call every 1 second and you can do whatever you want do in there.. or you set `repeats:YES` to `repeats:NO` so it will only get fire/call once.